# How to get Maven project version to the bash command line

Tags: bash, command-line, maven-2

Previous I issued a question on [how to change Maven project vesion from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3519005/update-a-maven-project-version-from-script) which lead me to a new issue.

Previously I was able to get the version number since the version was stored as a property that was easy to grep and parse from the command line (bash). Now that the pom.xml `<version>` element is used for this, it no longer is unique since all the dependencies and maybe some others too use this. I think there is no way to get the current version number with a bash script **without** external tools for parsing XML or some very context-aware `sed` command.

The most clean solution in my opinion would be for Maven to hand out this version information. I was thinking of writing a custom maven plugin for retrieving different properties but I thought I'd ask here first.

So, is there any easy way to get the value of `${project.version}` to the command line?

#### Solution

I had to `cd` to the directory manually but that can be done easily. In my bash script I have:

```sh
version=`cd $project_loc && mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-help-plugin:2.1.1:evaluate -Dexpression=project.version | sed -n -e '/^\[.*\]/ !{ /^[0-9]/ { p; q } }'`
```

Which gives me the current version that I can then advance. Grepping might be simpler but I thought I'd like as robust as possible, so I'm satisfied with the first line that starts with a number and try to handle this as a version number.

```sh
# Advances the last number of the given version string by one.
function advance_version () {
    local v=$1
    # Get the last number. First remove any suffixes (such as '-SNAPSHOT').
    local cleaned=`echo $v | sed -e 's/[^0-9][^0-9]*$//'`
    local last_num=`echo $cleaned | sed -e 's/[0-9]*\.//g'`
    local next_num=$(($last_num+1))
    # Finally replace the last number in version string with the new one.
    echo $v | sed -e "s/[0-9][0-9]*\([^0-9]*\)$/$next_num/"
}
```

And I use this by simply calling:

```sh
new_version=$(advance_version $version)
```

Comment: The solution seems to miss a ' to finish the sed expression.

Comment: Which sed exp? I can't seem to notice.

Comment: The script starting with "version=`cd $project_loc &&". The ' should be right before the ` at the end of the line.

Comment: Fixed that, thank you. I also noticed that the script in our code base doesn't use the -e parameter in the respective part. Unfortunately I can't verify if it's really needed.

Comment: make that a mvn -o for faster execution

Comment: You can replace that complex sed expression with a simple `grep -e '^[[:digit:]]'`

Comment: It's been a while but if I recall it right, the purpose of the sed is to strip and later to replace parts of the version string. I don't think you can do this with a single grep.

Comment: If you use -o as recommended by @NathanBubna then that will put maven in 'offline' mode. If you don't already have the maven help plugin and dependent jars downloaded then the build will fail. Got burned by that for a bit, hope it helps somebody else.

Comment: A simple `sed '/^\[.\+\] /d'` will delete all lines starting with `[...] ` from the output, leaving only the version number (unless there is an error during mvn execution).

Comment: Alternatively, `sed '/^[0-9]\+\./!d'` or `grep '^[0-9]\+\.'` will filter all lines not starting with `<digits><dot>`, which includes sneaky lines like `Downloading: <url>\n3/9 KB\r6/9 KB\r9/9 KB\rDownloaded: <url> <stats>`, where the line starts with `3/9 KB ...` but is outputted as `Downloaded: ...`.

Comment: before you start hating maven, read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50613762/1059372)

Answer (score 339, accepted):

The [Maven Help Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-help-plugin/) is somehow already proposing something for this:

> - [`help:evaluate`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-help-plugin/evaluate-mojo.html) evaluates Maven expressions given by the user in an interactive mode.

Here is how you would invoke it on the command line to get the `${project.version}`:

```
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-help-plugin:2.1.1:evaluate \
    -Dexpression=project.version
```

As [noted in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3545292/how-to-get-maven-project-version-to-the-bash-command-line#comment88615275_3545363) by [Seb T](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5116073/seb-t), to only print the version without the maven INFO logs, additionally use **`-q -DforceStdout`**:

```
mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression=project.version -q -DforceStdout
```

Comment: Great, thank you! Now one last issue for me is how should I get the version of a certain child project? I tried setting the `artifact` property, but it seems to give me `LATEST`.

Comment: @mkko: Do you mean, how to get the version of a specific child when running maven from an aggregating parent?

Comment: @pascal Yes. I understand I could just `cd` and run maven there but changing directories in a script is not nice, at least in this case.

Comment: @mkko: Yes, I understand too :) I just wanted to get confirmation. But I have to think a bit (and I'm not sure I'll find a nice solution).

Comment: @mkko: I didn't find a solution to "query" the child modules from the parent. And I don't know how to skip the `[INFO]` stuff so I'm afraid you'll have to grep what you want from the script.

Comment: Fine to find [INFO] messages are anoying for others too, I use mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression=project.basedir | grep -v '^\[INFO\]'

Comment: I'm removing all logging (INFO,WARNING,etc) and 'Download' messages with `mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-help-plugin:2.1.1:evaluate -Dexpression=project.version|grep -Ev '(^\[|Download\w+:)'`

Comment: You might want to also add `2> /dev/null` as otherwise you can get `Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS:`

Comment: Here's an approach I favor: `printf 'VERSION=${project.version}\n0\n' | mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-help-plugin:2.1.1:evaluate | grep '^VERSION'`

Comment: Additional suggestion so that this also works with a clean environment, for instance in a (dynamically created) jenkins slave:

Comment: To filter out everything except for the version, this works for me: `mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression=project.version | grep -e '^[^\[]'`

Comment: additionally if you want to build on @ash you can add `export` and then backticks (`) around their expression to make it set your environment variable to that

Comment: Based on previous answers, this gives a clean answer:
`printf 'VERSION=${project.version}' | mvn help:evaluate | grep '^VERSION=' | sed 's/^VERSION=//g'`

Comment: I had to modify the grep from @Chadwick slightly to include whitespace at the beginning, as some WARNING messages were getting printed with a carriage return (ascii 13): `mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-help-plugin:2.1.1:evaluate -Dexpression=project.version | grep -Ev '(^\s*\[|Download\w+:)'`

Comment: @Chadwick solution is broken with Maven 3.5.2, due to MNG-5457. This solution is by nature fragile due to the dependency on Maven log output.

Comment: @montoyaed posted the [best answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50613762/5116073) which simply is `mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression=project.version -q -DforceStdout`. To capture it in a variable in Bash use `version=$(mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression=project.version -q -DforceStdout)`

Comment: @Chadwick I figured that you also need to enable batch mode with maven `-B` option, or `"Downloaded"` lines don't get filtered.

Comment: I'm not sure the `-q` option suddenly hides all including the expression result.

Comment: do this to get only the version `mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-help-plugin:2.1.1:evaluate -Dexpression=project.version | tail -n 8 | head -n 1`

Answer (score 262):

Tom's solution with the [Exec Maven Plugin](https://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/) is much better, but still more complicated than it needs to be. For me it's as simple as:

```
MVN_VERSION=$(mvn -q \
    -Dexec.executable=echo \
    -Dexec.args='${project.version}' \
    --non-recursive \
    exec:exec)
```

Comment: I think this is the easiest way since it does not imply use of grep or similar things. Quick note: you may make it a bit shorter: `mvn -q -Dexec.executable="echo" -Dexec.args='${project.version}' --non-recursive exec:exec`

Comment: This solution worked well for me as I wanted to print groupId, artifactId and version.. `-Dexec.args='${project.groupId}:${project.artifactId}:${project.version}'`.

Comment: `[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.3.2:exec (default-cli) on project audit-events-processor-parent: Command execution failed. Cannot run program "maven" (in directory "/tmp"): error=2, No such file or directory` *shrug* yet another answer that doesn't work for me, oh well

Comment: Thank you this is the best solution I have seen so far, since it does not require to apply fragile grep/sed commands or similar

Comment: What is `set -o errexit`

Comment: You may want to add `</dev/null`. I observed maven exec plugin doing weird things when there is some file content being available on stdin.

Comment: I've tried this approach and the  `help:evaluate` approach, and for my project the difference is that `exec:exec` is 1.5 second slower than `help:evaluate`. Just testing for a single variable (`project.version`), no complex expression, in a multi-module setup without the `--non-recursive` flag (tried with this flag in my root reactor and the results were messy)

Comment: Hi! I'm quite new to this. How did you specify the plugin using this command?
Is it something like this?
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
</plugin>

What execution should I put in it?

Comment: That's exactly what I needed, assign the version to a variable and to use it later on in a pipeline. Thanks!

Answer (score 143):

After doing some research I found the following:

1. Maven has been blamed because integration with DevOps tools is not easy due to the fact that it does not follow some good practices regarding CLI tools, i.e:

> http://www.faqs.org/docs/artu/ch01s06.html (not available anymore)
> "The Unix Way"
> (ii) Expect the output of every program to become the input of another, as yet unknown, program. Don't clutter output with extraneous information. Avoid stringently columnar or binary input formats. Don't insist on interactive input.
> What does it actually mean?
> Your output should be:
>
> - "grepable": (One "record" per line)
> - "cutable": (Delimited "fields")
> - exit codes: 0 for success, nonzero for failure.
> - messaging (stderr) vs. output (stdout)

(ref: Make awesome command line apps with ruby by Dave Copeland Jan 18, 2012 https://youtu.be/1ILEw6Qca3U?t=372)

1. Honesty I think Dave Copeland was right when he said that maven does't play fairly with others. So I decided to give a look to maven's source code as well as to maven-help-plugin's source code as well. It seems that they have fixed a little bit the maven's -q switch (I was using version 3.5.3 at that time), so now if you pass it, you won't get all the annoying non-sense logging stuff that prevents maven from being used within automated scripts. So you should be able to use something like this:

   ```
   mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression=project.version -q
   ```

The problem is that this command prints nothing because by default the help plugin outputs through the logger which has been silenced by the -q switch. (latest available version of the plugin at that time was 3.1.0 released on June, 3rd 2018)

1. Karl Heinz Marbaise (https://github.com/khmarbaise) fixed it by adding an optional parameter that allows you to call it in the following way:

   ```
   mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression=project.version -q -DforceStdout
   ```

The commit description is available at: (https://github.com/apache/maven-help-plugin/commit/316656983d780c04031bbadd97d4ab245c84d014)

Again, you should always verify the exit code of the command and redirect all stderr to /dev/null on unix.

Comment: This would be my preferred solution and is also mentioned on the official [help pages](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-help-plugin/evaluate-mojo.html). However, it doesn't work for me. I am on MacOS with Maven v3.5.3. When I don't use the `-q` switch it prints out the version correctly (in between the log lines). Any ideas?

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.  It works in Windows and Linux (I didn't try Max OSX), and it's simple.  Thank you.

Comment: @montoyaedu Sorry for not responding. In the meantime I have updated to maven 3.5.4 which works fine with the `-q` switch.

Comment: @gucce I can confirm that maven version used affects this: with 3.5.2 (package version on debian 9) the output with `-q -DforceStdout` was empty, even ensuring version 3.1.0 of the plugin was used with pluginManagement) ; i configured maven wrapper with version 3.5.4 of maven, and it worked correctly

Comment: Finally, a practical solution without grep for 2019 - (this should become the accepted answer).  Works with [CI-friendly versions](https://maven.apache.org/maven-ci-friendly.html) too - tested on 3.3.9, 3.5.3, 3.5.4, 3.6.0

Comment: Add `-o` to run offline maven (a little bit faster): `mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression=project.version -q -o -DforceStdout` - but make sure you already have in local repo the evaluate plugin and all required dependencies

Comment: u need to make sure that the help plugin is at least version 3.1.0. For me it had little to do with the maven version itself but with the spring boot parent pom, so i had to overwrite the version!

Comment: Works for me on Mac. Apache Maven 3.5.4 - OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.14.5", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"

Comment: Do you know of a way to make this command run faster?  Even with -o this is taking ~2 minutes on my build agent.

Answer (score 54):

This is the **cleanest solution** there is:

```sh
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-help-plugin:3.2.0:evaluate \
-Dexpression=project.version -q -DforceStdout
```

Advantages:

- This works fine on **all** operating systems and **all** shells.
- No need for any external tools!
- [**important**] This works even if project version is inherited from parent `pom.xml`

Note:

- `maven-help-plugin` version `3.2.0` (and above) has `forceStdout` option. You may replace `3.2.0` in above command with a newer version from the list of [available versions of mvn-help-plugin](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-help-plugin) from artifactory, if available.
- Option `-q` suppresses verbose messages (`[INFO]`, `[WARN]` etc.)

Alternatively, you can add this entry in your `pom.xml`, under `plugins` section:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-help-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0</version>
</plugin>
```

and then run above command compactly as follows:

```sh
mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression=project.groupId -q -DforceStdout
```

If you want to fetch `groupId` and `artifactId` as well, check [this answer](/a/60023743).

Comment: This is IMHO the best answer as all the others failed to point out (as I found out the hard way) that you need at least version 3.1.0 of the maven-help-plugin because otherwise the -DforceStdout option [will be unknown](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MPH-144) and running "mvn -q help:evaluate ...." will produce no output at all.

Answer (score 52):

```
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-help-plugin:2.1.1:evaluate -Dexpression=project.version | grep -v '\['
```

Comment: make that mvn -o for faster execution

Comment: See my answer (quickshiftin) below which filters 'Downloaded:' lines too.

Comment: If you use -o as recommended by @NathanBubna then that will put maven in 'offline' mode. If you don't already have the maven help plugin and dependent jars downloaded then the build will fail. Got burned by that for a bit, hope it helps somebody else.

Comment: You might want to also add `2> /dev/null` as otherwise you can get `Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS:`

Comment: Is there a downside to just piping the command in this answer to `tail -1` ?

Comment: On Windows, replace the end of the command with `| findstr /v "["`.

Answer (score 52):

Why not use the right tool for the job?  Using xpath syntax is the best approach to retrieving the version number, since it is the intended method of accessing a XML data structure.  The expression below is traversing the pom using the "local name" of the elements, in other words ignoring namespace declarations which may or may not be present in the xml.

```
xmllint --xpath "//*[local-name()='project']/*[local-name()='version']/text()" pom.xml
```

Comment: @bobmarksie I second that; using maven and scrubbing the output with regexp's is painful.

Comment: What about a project that inherits from a parent pom.

Comment: "Why not use the right tool for the job?" IE !Maven?

Comment: I understand that using `mvn` is the right approach and `exec` plugin actually works nicely, but all mvn solutions do have to resolve and I am trying to bootstrap a build pipeline where dependency resolution will not work, so I am going to replace the `exec` approach with this solution. Luckily, I don't have to worry about versions inherited from parents.

Comment: This won't work with ci-friendly versioning,  where the version is a property like `${revision}` for example.  Ref. https://maven.apache.org/maven-ci-friendly.html

Comment: Doesn't work on windows git bash + relying on a new tool different than maven when we don't need is not a good practice.

Comment: I think that this is the best approach when you are dealing with older versions of maven (due to old jdk).

Comment: This is more suitable for interactive use due to its speed. And I'd say using an xml parser to parse a maven xml is still correct tooling.

Comment: Yes and there are also other similar tools like xmlstarlet. It is correct if run locally but in case you execute this in gitlab-ci, you will need to adjust your build docker image and adding such tooling. The advantage of maven is that is is already installed in our base image for building java soft.

Answer (score 35):

This will avoid the need for grepping off log entries from the output:

```
mvn -Dexec.executable='echo' -Dexec.args='${project.version}' --non-recursive exec:exec -q
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.

Comment: I think for this approach it is necessary to put the "-q" after mvn.

Comment: This is better than the accepted solution; no need to filter out maven noisy output.

Answer (score 19):

```
python -c "import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET; \
  print(ET.parse(open('pom.xml')).getroot().find( \
  '{http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0}version').text)"
```

As long as you have python 2.5 or greater, this should work.  If you have a lower version than that, install `python-lxml` and change the import to lxml.etree.  This method is quick and doesn't require downloading any extra plugins.  It also works on malformed pom.xml files that don't validate with xmllint, like the ones I need to parse.  Tested on Mac and Linux.

Answer (score 14):

There is also one option without need Maven:

```
grep -oPm1 "(?<=<version>)[^<]+" "pom.xml"
```

Comment: This one shows only the first occurrence in pom. In my case first occurrence gives parent pom version. But to be honest this is the answer I was looking for. It's much faster than solutions mentioned earlier and it's easy to modify it in order to get proper occurrence.
In order to get second occurrence use: `grep -oPm2 "(?<=<version>)[^<]+" pom.xml | sed -n 2p`
In order to get third occurrence use: `grep -oPm3 "(?<=<version>)[^<]+" pom.xml | sed -n 3p`
and so on

Comment: You are assuming the version element is the first occurrence, and it does not work when the assumption is invalid.

Comment: For those who are using this in a Docker build environement devops pipeline, the Docker image uses busy box to have some tools in the container and the embeded grep does not support the `-P` option and you need to rely on the `-E` option.  
The solution is then:  
`grep -oE "<version>[^<]+" "pom.xml" | sed -n '1{s/^<version>//p}'`
You can change the 1 in the sed to catch the correct iteration you are looking for.

Answer (score 13):

I kept running into side cases when using some of the other answers here, so here's yet another alternative.

```
version=$(printf 'VER\t${project.version}' | mvn help:evaluate | grep '^VER' | cut -f2)
```

Comment: `printf 'VER\t${project.version}' | mvn help:evaluate 2> /dev/null | grep '^VER' | cut -f2 `

Answer (score 11):

This is by far the easiest bash cut and paste solution:

```bash
VERSION=$(mvn exec:exec -Dexec.executable='echo' -Dexec.args='${project.version}' --non-recursive -q)
echo $VERSION
```

it echoes

```
1.4
```

Comment: Unknown lifecycle phase ".executable=echo". You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format

Comment: @chokdee which version of maven are you using?

Comment: 3.6.1 on Windows

Comment: @chokdee you have to write the entire line till `exec:exec`. The error you have happens when the plugin:goal part `exec:exec` part is missing

Comment: I did for sure. Same error. Maybe it's not running on windows?

Comment: @chokdee I double checked and this error message appears when the plugin:goal part `exec:exec` is missing. May be the problem is happening due your Windows console, try using a shell like bash.

Comment: @chokdee or maybe the quotes, have you tried single quote?

Comment: with following command it is runnable on windows too:
mvn exec:exec -Dexec.executable="c:\tools\cygwin64\bin\echo.exe" -Dexec.args="${project.version}" --non-recursive -q

Comment: @chokdee thanks for sharing, so you could try the plain solution adding `c:\tools\cygwin64\bin` in the `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: yes sure this will work

Comment: @chokdee thanks I will improve my answer with what we find out.

Answer (score 7):

If you don't mind to write the version into a temporary file, there is another solution (without grep/sed) that works well for me. (**EDIT**: see [rjrjr's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26514030/864936) for a much simpler solution without any temporary file hassle)

I use the [Exec Maven Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/) along with the `echo` binary. In contrast to the Maven Help Plugin, the Exec Plugin allows output redirection into a file, which can be used to bypass grep/sed, and makes it even possible to parse strange things like multiline version strings (with CDATA block in version tag), at least to a certain extent.

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

MVN_VERSION=""
VERSION_FILE=$( mktemp mvn_project_version_XXXXX )
trap "rm -f -- \"$VERSION_FILE\"" INT EXIT

mvn -Dexec.executable="echo" \
    -Dexec.args='${project.version}' \
    -Dexec.outputFile="$VERSION_FILE" \
    --non-recursive \
    --batch-mode \
    org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.3.1:exec > /dev/null 2>&1 ||
    { echo "Maven invocation failed!" 1>&2; exit 1; }

# if you just care about the first line of the version, which will be
# sufficent for pretty much every use case I can imagine, you can use
# the read builtin
[ -s "$VERSION_FILE" ] && read -r MVN_VERSION < "$VERSION_FILE"

# Otherwise, you could use cat.
# Note that this still has issues when there are leading whitespaces
# in the multiline version string
#MVN_VERSION=$( cat "$VERSION_FILE" )

printf "Maven project version: %s\n" "$MVN_VERSION"
```

Comment: This is a much better solution than the helper plugin, and you don't need all that i/o. Just add a -q flag and the only output will be the version. So: mvn -q -Dexec.executable="echo" -Dexec.args='${project.version}' --non-recursive org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.3.1:exec

Comment: rjrjr: Great! The only thing I need to mention here is error handling: If mvn fails, you get an invalid version string. So some validation is required, like checking mvn return code or the string itself.

Answer (score 6):

Just for the record, it's possible to configure Maven's Simple SLF4J logging directly in the command line to output only what we need by configuring:

- `org.slf4j.simpleLogger.defaultLogLevel=WARN` and
- `org.slf4j.simpleLogger.log.org.apache.maven.plugins.help=INFO`

as documented at http://www.slf4j.org/api/org/slf4j/impl/SimpleLogger.html

```
MAVEN_OPTS="\
-Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.defaultLogLevel=WARN \
-Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.log.org.apache.maven.plugins.help=INFO" \
mvn help:evaluate -o -Dexpression=project.version
```

As a result, one can run simply `tail -1` and get:

```
$ MAVEN_OPTS="\
-Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.defaultLogLevel=WARN \
-Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.log.org.apache.maven.plugins.help=INFO" \
mvn help:evaluate -o -Dexpression=project.version | tail -1

1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
```

Note that this is a one-liner. `MAVEN_OPTS` are being rewritten only for this particular `mvn` execution.

Answer (score 5):

I noticed some spurious `Downloaded:` lines coming in the output that were breaking my original assignment. Here's the filter I've settled on; hope it helps!

```
version=$(mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-help-plugin:2.1.1:evaluate -Dexpression=project.version | egrep -v '^\[|Downloading:' | tr -d ' \n')
```

**EDIT**

Not 100% sure why, but when running this through a post-build script in Jenkins, the output was coming out as `[INFO]version`, e.g. `[INFO]0.3.2`.

I dumped the output to a file and ran it through my first filter directly from BASH, it works fine.., so again, unsure what's going on in Jenkins land.

To get it 100% in Jenkins, I've added a follow-up `sed` filter; here's my latest

```
version=$(mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-help-plugin:2.1.1:evaluate -Dexpression=project.version | egrep -v '^\[|Downloading:' | tr -d ' \n' | sed -E 's/\[.*\]//g')
```

**EDIT**

One last note here.. I found out `tr` was *still* resulting in things like `/r/n0.3.2` (again only when running via Jenkins). Switched to `awk` and the problem has gone away! My final **working** result

```
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-help-plugin:2.1.1:evaluate -Dexpression=project.version \
| egrep -v '^\[|Downloading:' | sed 's/[^0-9\.]//g' | awk 1 ORS=''
```

Answer (score 5):

I've recently developed the [**Release Candidate**](http://smartcodeltd.co.uk/release-candidate-maven-plugin/) Maven plugin that solves this exact problem so that you don't have to resort to any hacky shell scripts and parsing the output of the `maven-help-plugin`.

For example, to print the version of your Maven project to a terminal, run:

```
mvn com.smartcodeltd:release-candidate-maven-plugin:LATEST:version
```

which gives output similar to `maven-help-plugin`:

```
[INFO] Detected version: '1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

However, you can also specify an **arbitrary output format** (so that the version could be picked up from the log by a CI server such as [TeamCity](https://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/)):

```
mvn com.smartcodeltd:release-candidate-maven-plugin:LATEST:version \
   -DoutputTemplate="##teamcity[setParameter name='env.PROJECT_VERSION' value='{{ version }}']"
```

Which results in:

```
[INFO] Detected version: '1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
##teamcity[setParameter name='env.PROJECT_VERSION' value='1.0.0-SNAPSHOT']
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

To save the output to a file (so that a CI server such as [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) could [use it](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin)):

```
mvn com.smartcodeltd:release-candidate-maven-plugin:LATEST:version \
   -DoutputTemplate="PROJECT_VERSION={{ version }}" \
   -DoutputUri="file://\${project.basedir}/version.properties"
```

The resulting `version.properties` file will look as follows:

```
PROJECT_VERSION=1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
```

---

On top of all the above, [Release Candidate](http://smartcodeltd.co.uk/release-candidate-maven-plugin/) also allows you to **set the version** of your project (which is something you'd probably do on your CI server) based on the API version you've defined in your POM.

If you'd like to see an example of Release Candidate being used as part of the Maven lifecycle, have a look at the `pom.xml` of my other open-source project - [Build Monitor for Jenkins](https://github.com/jan-molak/jenkins-build-monitor-plugin).

Answer (score 5):

A simple maven only solution

```
mvn -q -N org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.3.1:exec \
    -Dexec.executable='echo' \
    -Dexec.args='${project.version}'
```

And for bonus points parsed part of a version

```
mvn -q -N org.codehaus.mojo:build-helper-maven-plugin:3.0.0:parse-version \
    org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.3.1:exec \
    -Dexec.executable='echo' \
    -Dexec.args='${parsedVersion.majorVersion}.${parsedVersion.minorVersion}.${parsedVersion.incrementalVersion}'
```

Answer (score 4):

The easy to understand all-in-one solution that outputs the maven project version, and suppresses extraneous output from `[INFO]` and `Download` messages:

```
mvn -o org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-help-plugin:2.1.1:evaluate -Dexpression=project.version | grep -v '\['
```

Same thing, but split onto two lines:

```
mvn -o org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-help-plugin:2.1.1:evaluate \
      -Dexpression=project.version | grep -v '\['
```

Outputs: `4.3-SNAPSHOT`

So, using your `project.version` in a simple bash script:

```
projectVersion=`mvn -o org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-help-plugin:2.1.1:evaluate -Dexpression=project.version | grep -v '\['`
cd "target/"$projectVersion"-build"
```

Other solutions on this page didn't seem to combine all the tricks into one.

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me, offline and without depending on mvn:

```
VERSION=$(grep --max-count=1 '<version>' <your_path>/pom.xml | awk -F '>' '{ print $2 }' | awk -F '<' '{ print $1 }')
echo $VERSION
```

Answer (score 4):

I found right balance for me. After `mvn package` maven-archiver plugin creates `target/maven-archiver/pom.properties` with contents like this

```
version=0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
groupId=somegroup
artifactId=someArtifact
```

and I am using bash just to execute it

```
. ./target/maven-archiver/pom.properties
```

then

```
echo $version
0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
```

Of course this is not safe at all to execute this file, but execution can easily be converted into perl or bash script to read and set environment variable from that file.

Answer (score 3):

Should be easier since this bug is fixed in maven-help-plugin 3.0.0: [MPH-99 Evaluate has no output in quiet mode](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MPH-99).

Comment: Sadly 3.0.0 is not published

Answer (score 2):

Add the following plugin to your `pom.xml`

```
    ...
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-help-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>generate-version-file</id>
                <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>evaluate</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <expression>project.version</expression>
                    <output>${project.build.directory}/version.txt</output>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
    ...
```

This will generate a `target/version.txt` file as a normal part of your build.

All you then need to do to get this to the shell is the following:

```
#!/bin/sh
value=`cat target/version.txt`
echo "$value"
```

```
#!/bin/bash
value=$(<target/version.txt)
echo "$value"
```

Comment: This is a much cleaner approach compared to other answers.

Answer (score 1):

Exec plugin works without any output parsing because output can be redirected into file and injected back into the job environment via EnvInject plugin:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Either you have `mvn` give you the answer (as most answers suggest), or you extract the answer from the `pom.xml`. The only drawback of the second approach is that you can very easily extract the value of the `<version/>` tag, but it will be meaningful only if it's *literal*, that is, not a Maven property. I chose this approach anyway because:

- `mvn` is way to verbose and I simply don't like filtering its output.
- Starting `mvn` is very slow compared to reading the `pom.xml`.
- I always use literal values in `<version/>`.

[`mvn-version`](https://github.com/emcrisostomo/mvn-version) is a `zsh` shell script that uses `xmlstarlet` to read the `pom.xml` and print the version of the project (if it exists) or the version of the parent project (if it exists):

```
$ mvn-version .
1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
```

The advantage is that it's *way* quicker than running `mvn`:

```
$ time mvn-version .
1.1.0-SNAPSHOT
mvn-version .  0.01s user 0.01s system 75% cpu 0.019 total

$ time mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-help-plugin:2.1.1:evaluate \
> -Dexpression=project.version
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-help-plugin:2.1.1:evaluate   4.17s user 0.21s system 240% cpu 1.823 total
```

The difference on my machine is greater than two orders of magnitude.

Answer (score 1):

Base on the question, I use this script below to automatic increase my version number in all maven parent/submodules:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash  

# Advances the last number of the given version string by one.  
function advance\_version () {  
    local v=$1  
    \# Get the last number. First remove any suffixes (such as '-SNAPSHOT').  
  local cleaned=\`echo $v | sed \-e 's/\[^0-9\]\[^0-9\]\*$//'\`  
 local last\_num=\`echo $cleaned | sed \-e 's/\[0-9\]\*\\.//g'\`  
 local next\_num=$(($last\_num+1))  
  \# Finally replace the last number in version string with the new one.  
  echo $v | sed \-e "s/\[0-9\]\[0-9\]\*\\(\[^0-9\]\*\\)$/$next\_num/"  
}  

version=$(mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-help-plugin:3.2.0:evaluate -Dexpression=project.version -q -DforceStdout)  

new\_version=$(advance\_version $version)  

mvn versions:set -DnewVersion=${new\_version} -DprocessAllModules -DgenerateBackupPoms=false
```

Answer (score 1):

Quickest way that gets you just the text without all the trimmings

```
mvn help:evaluate -q -DforceStdout -D"expression=project.version"
```

Answer (score 0):

this is an edit from above

> cat pom.xml | grep "" | head -n 1 | sed -e "s/version//g" |
>   sed -e "s/\s*[<>/]*//g"

I tested it out on on the cmdline works well

grep "" pom.xml | head -n 1 | sed -e "s/version//g" | sed -e "s/\s*[<>/]*//g"

is another version of the same. I have a need to get the version number in Jenkins CI in k8s without mvn installed so this is most helpful

thanks all.

Comment: What if you have a parent POM? What if the dependencies are unusually placed before the project's GAV?

Answer (score 0):

I need exactly this requirement during my Travis job but with multiple values.
I start with [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3545363/7500389) but when calling multiple time this is very slow (I need 5 expresions).

I wrote a simple maven plugin to extract pom.xml's values into .sh file.

https://github.com/famaridon/ci-tools-maven-plugin

```
mvn com.famaridon:ci-tools-maven-plugin:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT:environment -Dexpressions=project.artifactId,project.version,project.groupId,project.build.sourceEncoding
```

Will produce that:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
CI_TOOLS_PROJECT_ARTIFACTID='ci-tools-maven-plugin';
CI_TOOLS_PROJECT_VERSION='0.0.1-SNAPSHOT';
CI_TOOLS_PROJECT_GROUPID='com.famaridon';
CI_TOOLS_PROJECT_BUILD_SOURCEENCODING='UTF-8';
```

now you can simply source the file

```
source .target/ci-tools-env.sh
```

Have fun.

Answer (score 0):

One alternative would be to parse with yq (https://github.com/kislyuk/yq) like so:

```
cat pom.xml | xq -r '.project.version'
```

Notice the executable is xq not yq

To get xq, install yq like so `pip install yq`

Answer (score 0):

In docker containers with only busybox available I use awk.

```sh
version=$(
 awk '
  /<dependenc/{exit}
  /<parent>/{parent++};
  /<version>/{
    if (parent == 1) {
      sub(/.*<version>/, "");
      sub(/<.*/, "");
      parent_version = $0;
    } else {
      sub(/.*<version>/, "");
      sub(/<.*/, "");
      version = $0;
      exit
    }
  }
  /<\/parent>/{parent--};
  END {
    print (version == "") ? parent_version : version
  }' pom.xml
)
```

Notes:

- If no artifact version is given parent version is printed instead.
- Dependencies are required to come after artifact and parent version. (This could be overcome quite easily but I don't need it.)

Answer (score 0):

Using the [Build Helper Maven Plugin/ build-helper:parse-version](https://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/parse-version-mojo.html), we can get/read:

- the current `project version`
- the `major`/`minor`/`incremental` versions
- the `nextMajor`/`nextMinor`/`nextIncremental` versions:

```
projectVersion=$(mvn build-helper:parse-version help:evaluate -Dexpression=project.version  -q -DforceStdout)

majorVersion=$(mvn build-helper:parse-version help:evaluate -Dexpression=parsedVersion.majorVersion  -q -DforceStdout)
minorVersion=$(mvn build-helper:parse-version help:evaluate -Dexpression=parsedVersion.minorVersion  -q -DforceStdout)
incrementalVersion=$(mvn build-helper:parse-version help:evaluate -Dexpression=parsedVersion.incrementalVersion  -q -DforceStdout)

nextMajorVersion=$(mvn build-helper:parse-version help:evaluate -Dexpression=parsedVersion.nextMajorVersion  -q -DforceStdout)
nextMinorVersion=$(mvn build-helper:parse-version help:evaluate -Dexpression=parsedVersion.nextMinorVersion  -q -DforceStdout)
nextIncrementalVersion=$(mvn build-helper:parse-version help:evaluate -Dexpression=parsedVersion.nextIncrementalVersion  -q -DforceStdout)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression=project.version | sed -e 1h -e '2,3{H;g}' -e '/\[INFO\] BUILD SUCCESS/ q' -e '1,2d' -e '{N;D}' | sed -e '1q'
```

I'm just adding small `sed` filter improvement I have recently implemented to extract `project.version` from maven output.

Comment: Maven command works for me but sed doesn't `sed: 1: "2,3{H;g}` `": extra characters at the end of g command`

Answer (score -1):

I am using a one-liner in my unix shell ...

> cat pom.xml | grep "" | head -n 1 | sed -e "s/version//g" |
>   sed -e "s/\s*[<>/]*//g"

You can hide this line in a shell script or as an alias.

Answer (score -2):

```
VERSION=$(head -50 pom.xml | awk -F'>' '/SNAPSHOT/ {print $2}' | awk -F'<' '{print $1}')
```

This is what I used to get the version number, thought there would have been a better maven way to do so

Answer (score -2):

```
VERSION=$(mvn -version | grep 'Apache Maven' | grep -o '[0-9].[0-9].[0-9]')
echo $VERSION
```

Comment: The question is about getting the Maven project version, not the version of Maven itself.