# How to get Maven groupId, artifactId & project version to the command line

Tags: maven, command-line

I would like to retrieve from the command line the *groupId, the artifactId & the version* of a Maven project.

The proposed solution in this topic "[How to get Maven project version to the bash command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3545292/how-to-get-maven-project-version-to-the-bash-command-line)" is to use the following plugin:

`mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-help-plugin:2.2:evaluate -Dexpression=project.artifactId`

It works well but I can't figure out how to set, at the same time, the `project.groupId, project.artifactId & project.version` to the *-Dexpression* argument.

I would avoid launching 3 times the Maven command with a different *-Dexpression* argument each time...

Thks

---

For the moment, I retrieve data by doing the following:

```
local pom_groupid=`mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-help-plugin:2.2:evaluate -Dexpression=project.groupId |grep -Ev '(^\[|Download\w+:)'`
local pom_artifactid=`mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-help-plugin:2.2:evaluate -Dexpression=project.artifactId |grep -Ev '(^\[|Download\w+:)'`
local pom_version=`mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-help-plugin:2.2:evaluate -Dexpression=project.version |grep -Ev '(^\[|Download\w+:)'`
```

Answer (score 30):

Here's another approach that doesn't require creating a Maven plugin even though Olivier has shown that it is pretty easy to make one.

> mvn -q -Dexec.executable=echo -Dexec.args='${project.groupId} ${project.artifactId} ${project.version}' --non-recursive exec:exec 2>/dev/null

Note that this is tailored to the linux environment. On windows you could probably create a batch file that prints its input or something.

One drawback of this approach is that you may have to add `| grep -v "something"` to the very end of the command above (after the `2>/dev/null`) to filter out some text that maven prints to stdout. In my case I only had one line of text to filter that'll only appear at my company.

Credit where it is due: I adapted this info from [this other StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3545292/how-to-get-maven-project-version-to-the-bash-command-line).

Comment: One drawback for this approach is that all the dependencies need to be resolved before extracting the properties. There exists cases where you do not want to resolve the dependencies and simply want the properties declared within the pom file. In that case, `help:evaluate` is still the better choice.

Comment: Hi! I'm quite new to this. How did you specify the plugin using this command? Is it something like this? <plugin> <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId> <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId> <version>3.0.0</version> </plugin> What execution should I put in it?

Answer (score 27):

This is the **cleanest solution** available:

```sh
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-help-plugin:3.2.0:evaluate \
-Dexpression=project.groupId -q -DforceStdout

mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-help-plugin:3.2.0:evaluate \
-Dexpression=project.artifactId -q -DforceStdout

mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-help-plugin:3.2.0:evaluate \
-Dexpression=project.version -q -DforceStdout
```

Advantages:

- This works fine on **all** operating systems (OS X, Ubuntu, Windows etc.) and on **all** shells (bash, zsh etc.)
- [very important] This works fine even if `groupId` or `version` is inherited from parent `pom.xml`.

  - Note that `xmllint`-based solutions **fail** when POM properties are inherited!
- Zero dependency on external tools! (notice that I'm **not** using any `echo` or `grep`)

Alternatively, you can add this entry in your `pom.xml`, under `plugins` section:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-help-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0</version>
</plugin>
```

and then run commands compactly as follows:

```sh
mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression=project.groupId -q -DforceStdout
mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression=project.artifactId -q -DforceStdout
mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression=project.version -q -DforceStdout
```

Please note:

- `maven-help-plugin` version `3.2.0` (and above) has `forceStdout` option. You may replace `3.2.0` in above command with a newer version from the list of [available versions of mvn-help-plugin](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-help-plugin) from artifactory, if available.
- Option `-q` suppresses verbose messages.

Comment: Didn't work for me on Powershell. I had to wrap the expression in single quotes `-Dexpression='project.groupId'`

Comment: How can I use above command to get artifactId for multi-module project ?

Answer (score 9):

A simpler command, derived from @Patrick's answer to get the "GAV" format:

```
echo '${project.groupId}:${project.artifactId}:${project.version}' | mvn -N -q -DforceStdout help:evaluate
```

In case of an external *.pom file to evaluate, this command may be useful:

```
echo '${project.groupId}:${project.artifactId}:${project.version}' | mvn -N -q -DforceStdout help:evaluate -f <path-to-pom-file>
```

Comment: To get different properties and assign them to shell variables: `IFS=: read id version <<< "$(echo '${project.artifactId}:${project.version}' | mvn --quiet --non-recursive help:evaluate -DforceStdout)"`

Comment: @GJ. Thanks for the IFS + read suggestion.

Answer (score 6):

In bash, consider the following lines I use to get them.
It uses **xmllint** and some string manipulation.

```
GROUP_ID=`echo -e 'setns x=http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0\ncat /x:project/x:groupId/text()' | xmllint --shell pom.xml | grep -v /`
ARTIFACT_ID=`echo -e 'setns x=http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0\ncat /x:project/x:artifactId/text()' | xmllint --shell pom.xml | grep -v /`
VERSION=`echo -e 'setns x=http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0\ncat /x:project/x:version/text()' | xmllint --shell pom.xml | grep -v /`
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Currently I do almost the same thing as you but it's still three different calls...

Comment: Still, this is fast and simple. Don't over engineer it :-)

Comment: This may not work if the version is inherited from the parent.

Answer (score 6):

You can specify multiple expressions for the maven-help-plugin (so you only have to run it once) and then extract them from the captured output by grep'ing for the 'key' you specified:

```
output=$(printf \
    'LOCAL_REPOSITORY=${settings.localRepository}\n'\
    'GROUP_ID=${project.groupId}\n'
    'ARTIFACT_ID=${project.artifactId}\n'\
    'POM_VERSION=${project.version}\n0\n' \
  | mvn help:evaluate --non-recursive )

localRepository=$(echo "$output" | grep '^LOCAL_REPOSITORY' | cut -d = -f 2)
groupId=$(echo "$output" | grep '^GROUP_ID' | cut -d = -f 2)
artifactId=$(echo "$output" | grep '^ARTIFACT_ID' | cut -d = -f 2)
pomVersion=$(echo "$output" | grep '^POM_VERSION' | cut -d = -f 2)
```

Other solutions that parse the pom.xml work for simple use cases, however they fall short if you need to access something that is either not defined in the pom.xml (`settings.localRepository`) or a potentially derived value (`project.version`).

Comment: Thank you, this works great! I added options `-q -DforceStdout` to avoid some clutter.

Answer (score 5):

I had an issue with echo and interactiveMode false + a custom profile.. turns out you can specify **all 3** (or 4 if you need the packaging) in the **expression** by omitting the first **${** and last **}** ex:

```
mvn -N -q -DforceStdout help:evaluate -Dexpression='project.groupId}:${project.artifactId}:${project.packaging}:${project.version' -f ./xpp3-1.1.3.4.O.pom
```

Or more **elegantly** (this will include packaging) with **project.id**:

```
-Dexpression=project.id
```

This is because the source code wraps the expression:

```
handleResponse( "${" + expression + "}", output );
```

Source / Credits:
https://github.com/paul-hammant/maven-plugins/blob/master/maven-help-plugin/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugins/help/EvaluateMojo.java

The **error** I got when using **interactiveMode** **false** and a **profile** with -P:

```
[ERROR] Maven is configured to NOT interact with the user for input. This Mojo requires that 'interactiveMode' in your settings file is flag to 'true'.
```

Comment: Unfortunately, project.id returns groupId:artifactId:packaging:version.  The dependency:copy goal, for example, requires groupId:artifactId:version[:packaging[:classifier]].

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes, we forget how easy it is to tailor Maven to our need : [here is a very simple custom plugin](https://github.com/olivierdemeijer/helper-maven-plugin) that do one thing, concatenate groupId,artifactId and version and send it to out.

Check it out, run `mvn clean install` (local) or `mvn clean deploy`(repository) to make it available in your environment.

Then run `mvn my.helper.maven.plugin:helper-maven-plugin:me` or `mvn helper:me` (after adding `<pluginGroup>my.helper.maven.plugin</pluginGroup>` to your `<pluginGroups>` in your Maven settings.xml) to have the following line displayed on console :

`my.help.me={project.groupId}:{project.artifactId}:{project.version}`

To filter out everything but this line, all you have to do is running :

```
mvn helper:me| grep ^my.help.me=
```

or even simpler :

```
mvn -q helper.me
```

Comment: Thanks for your plugin, it works well. but unfortunately the environment can't be upgraded with "custom" plugins (settings.xml) and the _builded pom_ is in read only too. Currently I've to use common/default tools for this script... KR

Comment: As long as you have a way to push the plugin in your maven repo, using the "long" command should work, without the need to modified settings.xml or pom.xml. But I understand that sometimes, 'no' means 'no' ;)

Answer (score 3):

I prefer avoiding new dependencies where I can solve the solution easily. Using powershell:

```
[xml]$pomXml = Get-Content .\pom.xml

# version
Write-Host $pomXml.project.version

# groupId
Write-Host $pomXml.project.groupId

# artifactId
Write-Host $pomXml.project.artifactId
```

Comment: Note that this will only work for POMs using literal values for these fields, as opposed to interpolation.

Answer (score 0):

xmlstarlet is handy for xml data extraction and way faster than maven.
eg:

```
artifact="$(xmlstarlet sel -N my=http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 -t -m my:project -v my:artifactId pom.xml)"
```