# How can I cut the version number out of a pom file in bash

Tags: xml, bash, maven, sed, grep

I have a pom file that has the following information:

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.site.camera</groupId>
  <artifactId>proj3</artifactId>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <version>2.6</version>
  <name>Proj 3</name>
```

I am writing a bash script and want to be able to open this file (pom.xml) and cut out the version (eg. 2.6 in this case). I am doing this because as I update the version I want the rest of my script to update with it.

Things that I have tried:

```
var=$(grep <version>2.6</version> pom.xml)
echo $var
```

Note that I have multiple version parameters in the pom file. And I need this specific version which is surrounded with this name, packaging, artifactId etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get Maven project version to the bash command line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3545292/how-to-get-maven-project-version-to-the-bash-command-line)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>The simplest way is to use GNU grep's perl-compatible regexes</strike>

```
grep -oP '<version>\K[^<]+' pom.xml
```

With sed, you'd write

```
sed -n 's/^[[:blank:]]*<version>\([^<]\+\).*/\1/p' pom.xml
```

Thanks to David W.'s thoughtful commentary: the solution must use an XML parser. `xmlstarlet` is one such tool:

```
ver=$( xmlstarlet sel -t -v /project/version pom.xml )
```

And just to be different, ruby comes with an XML parser in its standard library:

```
ruby -r rexml/document -e 'puts REXML::Document.new(File.new(ARGV.shift)).elements["/project/version"].text' pom.xml
```

Comment: What if there are other lines with a version number in the pom? Every dependency and plugin will have a version number.

Comment: The `<version/>` attribute is found all throughout the `pom.xml`. Take a look at this one for [commons-lang3](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.apache.commons%7Ccommons-lang3%7C3.3.2%7Cjar).  There's a parent `<version>`, an artifact `<version>`, and three dependencies with `<version>`. There are five in the `<reporting>` section and 2 more in the `<build>` section. This grep will pick them all up.

Comment: xmlstarlet line didn't work for me, instead it did pretty well ->
version=$( xmlstarlet sel -t -v '/_:project/_:version' pom.xml  )

Answer (score 8):

Some people [object to parsing XML with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags). Here's how you can do it correctly and robustly with `xmlstarlet`:

```
$ cat pom.xml 
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.site.camera</groupId>
  <artifactId>proj3</artifactId>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <version>2.6</version>
  <name>Proj 3</name>
</project>

$ xmlstarlet sel -t -v '/project/version' pom.xml 
2.6
```

This works equally well after XML tools and editors have had their way with your document:

```
$ cat pom.xml 
<project>
  <version><![CDATA[2]]>&#x002E;6
  </version>
</project>

$ xmlstarlet sel -t -v '/project/version' pom.xml 
2.6
```

**Edit**: As a testament to Doing It Right(tm), this solution still works fine after it was pointed out that there will be a lot of different version tags.

Comment: Other people might object to parsing maven configuration using DOM :) +1. But I have another solution.

Comment: When the pom file starts with a `<project xmlns=...>`, the select statement requires to define the namespace as well. I've added an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70003714/1076463) illustrating this.

Answer (score 6):

Using maven you do it this way:

```
echo '${project.version}' | mvn help:evaluate | grep -v '^[[]'
```

Comment: Very nice. Sadly none of `-q`, `-l /dev/null` or `2> /dev/null` will convince `mvn` to separate output from buildlog, so the grep seems to be the only way.

Answer (score 3):

try like this:

```
var=$(grep -Po '<version>\K[^<]*' pom.xml)
echo $var
```

output:

```
2.6
```

- -P : use perl regexp format
- -o : print matching part only

Answer (score 2):

[The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29420859/1076463) from [that other guy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1899640/that-other-guy) illustrates the correct approach of using an xml parser, but it cannot deal with namespaces in the `pom.xml` file.

If your POM file starts like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<project
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                             http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
>
 ...
</project>
```

you'll need to add the namespace when using `xmlstarlet`:

```sh
xmlstarlet select \
  -N x="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" \
  --template --value-of "/x:project/x:version" \
  pom.xml
```

Answer (score 1):

Or without perl compatible regular expressions using **parameter expansion/substring extraction**:

```
$ var=$(grep '<version>' pom.xml); ver=${var%<*}; ver=${ver#*>}; echo $ver
2.6
```

I would prefer the perl compatibile RE if you have that available.

**Note:** As pointed out by David W. this works for the example given, but will return **multiple** `version` strings if the input file has more than one line containing `<version>`. The full `pom.xml` file referenced below in the comments contains **multiple** `<version>` strings. An additional loop will be required to process all `version` lines and without a unique tag, it is not possible to determine which `version` is the desired version. For example parsing the current full `pom.xml` with:

```
$ for i in $(grep '<version>' pom.xml); do ver=${i%<*}; ver=${ver#*>}; echo "version: $ver"; done
```

Returns:

```
version: 33
version: 3.3.2
version: 4.11
version: 2.4
version: 3.2
version: 2.9.1
version: 2.5.2
version: 2.5.1
version: 2.4
version: 3.0.1
version: 2.4
version: 2.0
version: 1.7
```

Comment: Look at the `pom.xml` for [commons-lang3](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.apache.commons%7Ccommons-lang3%7C3.3.2%7Cjar). There are almost a dozen `<version>`  elements your `grep` will pick up.

Comment: Well, that does change things a bit! I was just going by the example given. Thanks for the heads up. I'll see if it is salvagable, if not I'll note it.

Answer (score 0):

My Requirement was also similar. We are using SNAPSHOT at the end of our version so I did this to find out the Version number (Extension of David's answer)

```
for i in $(grep '<version>' pom.xml); do
    #echo "$i"; 
    ver=${i%<*}; 
    ver=${ver#*>};
    if [[ $ver == *"SNAPSHOT"* ]]
        then
            echo "$ver";
    fi 

done
```

And It gives me an output; Which I wanted

> 1.09-SNAPSHOT