# how to find the released number of jar using maven in linux bash script?

Tags: linux, maven, maven-release-plugin

We use maven release plugin, which is used to release jar to remote repository. We also use `-DautoVersionSubmodules=true` while releasing which automatically updates snapshot version in pom to next version.
Now, after release is successful, we want to find the released version number of jar in linux bash script.

eg:- Suppose my current snapshot version in pom.xml is `<version>1.50-SNAPSHOT</version>`. Now, when we perform release, 1.50 version jar is released to remote repository and pom.xml is auto updated to `<version>1.51-SNAPSHOT</version>` by plugin. After release, in my bash script I should get "1.50" release number. Can anyone help how to achieve this ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get Maven project version to the bash command line](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3545292/1700321)

Comment: Are you using git as your SCM?

Comment: For Apache commons-lang-2.6.jar what works is unzip or jar -x it, cd to META-INF in the resulting folder, grep "Implementation-Version:"  in MANIFEST.mf and sed -e 's/Implementation-Version: ///g' which results in 2.6.