# Does start-class take any argument to supply a value for main class?

Tags: java, spring, maven

I got myself up and running with Spring, maven using Spring Boot. You may check the below link for details -

https://ashikuzzaman.wordpress.com/2015/06/04/spring-with-maven-using-spring-boot/

In my pom.xml I have the following properties defined.

```
<properties>
    <java.version>1.7</java.version>
    <!-- The main class to start by executing java -jar -->
    <start-class>com.github.ashikuzzaman.javaapichecks.spring.RawLinkedListTypes</start-class>
</properties>
```

I wanted to pass one or more runtime arguements to get into the arguement list that main() accepts. Can I do this via a parameter passing in start-class or main-class?

Comment: You may see the link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3545292/how-to-get-maven-project-version-to-the-bash-command-line

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you are trying to give some value for `java.version` while you are using `mvn package` command from terminal. Then you can use it -

```
mvn package "-Djava.version=1.7"
```

Comment: I think the question regards passing data to the `main` function, which this doesn't appear to address directly.

Comment: Yes, I was talking about passing data like we pass in array of arguements to main method. For example, I want to say java com.mypackage.MyTestProgram sort 5 8 9 1