# How to get Maven project version to the Windows command line or Batch file?

Tags: windows, maven, command-line

There is the same question answered for Linux - [How to get Maven project version to the bash command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3545292/how-to-get-maven-project-version-to-the-bash-command-line)

But what about Windows?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Worked for me in command line:

```
mvn -q --non-recursive "-Dexec.executable=cmd" "-Dexec.args=/C echo ${project.version}" "org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.3.1:exec"
```

In a batch file:

```
for /f %%i in ('call mvn -q --non-recursive "-Dexec.executable=cmd" "-Dexec.args=/C echo ${project.version}" "org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.3.1:exec"') do set PVERSION=%%i
echo %PVERSION%
```

Comment: Awesome !! thank you it's working, this is exactly what i need