# Get version number of a dependency from pom.xml using command line and use that version number to tag a docker image

Tags: java, docker, maven, cmd, pom.xml

I have a pom file. I want to read the  version of the first dependency in the dependencies tag and use that version to tag our docker image.

I am using this command to get the project version.

mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression=project.parent.version:1 -q -DforceStdout

I want to get the version of the first dependency using command line , and from there it will passed onto the docker tag and docker push.

[image]

Comment: Codes and logs should not be attached as images, but in text format. See the following guide. [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) / 
[do-not-upload-images-of-code-errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: also, searching before the question is essential. Have you checked the link? [how-to-get-maven-project-version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3545292/how-to-get-maven-project-version-to-the-bash-command-line)

Comment: Why do you like to get that version? And put that into a docker image? In your build the version of your artifact will always be 5.0.0 based on the given parent and not overriding the version....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try

`project.dependencies[0].version`

but probably the most stable method would be to define the version as a property and then read the property with `help:evaluate`.