# Use pom version to create git tag in Bamboo

Tags: git, maven, bamboo

The customer for the current project I'm working on uses Bamboo for building. I'm new to Bamboo. I'm creating a build plan for a Java/maven project. I want the build to add a tag to the git branch, which combines the version number from `pom.xml` (e.g. 1.0.1) and the Bamboo build numbe (e.g 53). The example would create a tag 1.0.1.53.

The build number is easy, it just the `${bamboo.buildNumber}` variable, but how can I construct the tag using the `pom.xml`?

Answer (score 1):

You could try to [parse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3545292/how-to-get-maven-project-version-to-the-bash-command-line) pom version and use git to tag the current revision in a script task.